# How can one tell if a field has wrapped in Crystal Reports 2008?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In Crystal Reports 2008, I need to have an accurate count of all of the lines that have been displayed in a sub report.

I'm using a shared variable and incrementing as needed when lines display. The only problem I'm having now is when a field wraps. We are not using a fixed width font, so going by field length does not solve the issue, as 'i' is not as wide as 'w' and so on.

Is there a way to find out if the data in a field will be wrapped, and if so how many lines it wraps to, or is there a way to find out what the height of the section that the field is in (or the field itself) has grown too?

Or, is there an even better way to count how many lines have actually displayed on the sub report?

Comment: If a record wraps; do you want to count it as two+ lines or one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you describe.

If you used a fixed-width font, you could then do some math based based on "it wraps at X characters" do if length of string is 100, then it went 2 lines, etc.